# unable to upgrade php in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, php7

I am trying to update php from 7.2 to 7.4, but getting error. I am trying with the following command as root:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

the error:

```
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/ppas: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852) Failed to add key.
```

Could you please advise how to update php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt-Get Update Failing because of Certificate Validation](https://serverfault.com/questions/1093511/apt-get-update-failing-because-of-certificate-validation)

Comment: I tried it and I get the same error

Comment: remember that 1804 will end of support on 04/23 so consider to upgrade. you should retry the above as currently its a duplicate of the already posted notice from Gerald